# Objective-C Reflection - Getting generic type of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I'm currently trying to read the properties of a class with reflection in Objective-C.
Its working all well expect with my NSArray.

This is my property:

```c
@property(nonatomic) NSArray<CustomObject*>* tabs;
```

I can successfully access my properties of my class with:

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &propertyCount);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = properties[i];
            const char *propertyName = property_getName(property);
            const char *attrs = property_getAttributes(property);
}
```

So my property name is **tabs**. All good. But the attributes are **"T@"NSArray",&,N,V_tabs"**

How do I get the information about the generic type of my NSArray?
Thx in advance

Comment: Not sure if possible ... if array is NOT empty why not use class of first object? Even then it is no guarantee as you can put any object in NSArray but maybe this approach can help?

Comment: Array is empty.

Comment: Generics are only used by compiler AFAIK so if the array is empty you cannot get its generic type during runtime. Maybe you can plug it with a sample? Otherwise I don't think it is possible.

Comment: The generic specifier does not exist in runtime, it's a compile time check so getting it the way you intended is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

unless nothing is stored with the indexedSubscript (aka `[index]`) of your NSArray it is empty and only Xcode knows about your intention what type you want to store there.

so

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray<CustomObject*>* tabs;
```

is equivalent to

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray<NSObject*>* tabs;
```

is equivalent to

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray<id>* tabs;
```

is equivalent to

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray* tabs;
```

The list above is not 100% correct because Xcode could throw an error when you try to mix up datatypes and try to compile and so it should not get to the point where you store wrong datatypes.

Unless no object is allocated it does not take memory and so it can not be asked at runtime.

If it is important in your design pattern you could create your own datatype that can be accessed via indexedSubscripts and also keep informations of your intention of what datatype you keep there even if *empty*. But it is worth thinking about if this is then still a design pattern that fits what you wanted to achieve.